# Why do so many groups of people (marketers, UX, finance) use a 'funnel' as a metaphor

Tags: popular-refrains, metaphors, analogy

The concept of a funnel is invariably used as an explanation of a flow where you start with a large base group of something (usually customers) and end up at the end with a much smaller subset that is the value providing group (for ex. customers that purchase). This image illustrates this point.

[image]

Now having **personally** used a funnel before, I know this to not be true, and it's not just me, Wikipedia seems to agree ['It is used to channel liquid or fine-grained substances into containers with a small opening. Without a funnel, spillage would occur.'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funnel). My only remotely reasonable explanation as to why this object is chosen is its shape, which sort of makes sense until you realise they also got that one wrong, as it has a much narrower base, making something like a pyramid much more appropriate (similar to the famous "food group pyramid)

Am I just missing something? Is there a mystical funnel + colander combination out there that pours liquids into a smaller container while also losing various amounts of liquid or is there a more realistic explanation to this usage?

Comment: I suspect it's derived from _filter funnel_ and just lost the _filter_ part, even though it's the _filter_ part that seems to be important. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/filter_funnel

Comment: Sounds plausible enough. I've seen these before, though afaik they're used for filtering out impurities and you would still end up with the same amount of liquid in the end? Feel free to make this an answer as well :)

Comment: I think it depends on what bit you want to keep - filtering gold out of solution always ends up in disposal of the nasty cyanide solution but retention of the solids. Someone will probably come up with a proper answer possibly including an early use of funnel to mean 'filter' - I'm just guessing really. 'Funnelly' enough - in the UK _filter lane_ is used to mean _separate the traffic_ but motorcyclists also _filter_ between lanes of traffic, which is actually more like _seeping_.

Comment: its a coffee filter!

Comment: I guess I don't read the right magazines, because I don't see this sort of thing very often at all.  But one can see that it's an attractive way for advertisers to over-simplify a concept, especially one that has $$$ flowing out the bottom.  (Have no idea what this has to do with English, though.)

Comment: @HotLicks in all fairness it's an easy thing to miss. It does pop up more than a lot as a concept in certain fields, particularly in internet startups, but most likely in sales as well. As for what it has to do with english: it's a comparison that English speakers somehow find acceptable and I was curious as to the history/logic of the comparison. It makes no sense to me personally to use an item with such a specific function (aside from the shape) to express this idea so I figured to ask others :)

Comment: I would guess that the same diagram is used in German, Japanese, et al, to the extent that people speaking those languages are susceptible to marketing hype.  Certainly has nothing to do with the word "funnel".

Comment: I wouldn't expand that so quickly. Considering a very large chunk of marketing and management theory was created by American entrepreneurs and social scientists, in English, I would expect that it very well may have a connection.

Comment: Think about it - you are expecting marketers and graphic designers to know how a real funnel works.  If they did, they would not be marketers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that is just a question of the shape ( like an inverted piramid) which is intuitive and easy to use to convey the idea of different results from a sequence of decreasing quantities,  (it also suggest the image that from the end of the funnel you get your final result).

[Funnel and Pyramid Charts](http://anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/Funnel-Pyramid-Chart.html?fromtree):

> - Funnel charts are so-called Accumulation charts and they show percentage ratio. Funnel charts are often used to represent stages in a sales process and show the amount of potential revenue for each stage. This type of chart can also be useful in identifying potential problem areas in an organization’s sales processes. A funnel chart is similar to a stacked percent bar chart.
> - You can turn your funnel into Cone or Pyramid you should just set neck_height and min_width to "0" and set mode="circular" - to get Conical shape, or mode="square" - to show Pyramid

Answer (score 4):

Funnels System is **Sales Enablement Best Practices** designed to integrate Marketing with Sales so as to build quality pipeline consisting of sales opportunities that have the highest probability of closing in the shortest time...

> [A sales funnel is **an inverted pyramid**](http://www.entrepreneurial-insights.com/effectively-manage-sales-funnel/) that draws potential
>   customers through a company’s sales process.  As the name indicates,
>   it is wide at the top because customers with all level of engagement
>   enter and eventually the strongest leads are channeled to the bottom
>   to be turned into successful sales.

■ **funnel acts as a filter**: It helps focus attention on the customers most likely to purchase the product.

Comment: I know what all those words mean, but the answer makes no sense...

Comment: @OrangeDog - It's marketing.  It's not supposed to make sense.